# How to get count of number elements which are greater than current element in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have an arraylist [10,11,1,2,3,6,11,10]. For each element, I want to get count of elements which are greater than current element.

For example, for 10, only 11 is greater than it and there are 2 occurances of it.
For 11, nothing is greater than it. So 0.

So we have to print output like 
10,2
11,0
1,7
2,6
3,5
6,4
11,0
10,2

Comment: Hey , give us the code and where is your problem in the code. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have **you** tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public void greaterCounter(List<Integer> input){
  for (Integer i : input){
    Integer count = 0;
    for (Integer j : input){
      if (i < j)
        count++;
    }
    System.out.print(i+","+count+" ");
  }
}
```

Comment: you can add a space to the end of print statement to make the output nicer. Like: `System.out.print(i+","+count+" ");`

Comment: Right, edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Count
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 10);
    Map<Integer, Integer> output = new HashMap<>();
    for (Integer in : input)
    {
      // I've used Java 8's stream API here. But if you are using Java 7 or lesser,
      // you can use another "for" loop here to filter items.
      int count = (int) input.stream().filter(i -> i > in).count();
      output.put(in, count);
    }

    for (Integer in : input)
    {
      System.out.print(in + "," + output.get(in) + " ");
    }
  }
}
```